# unsigned long long to string convert

Tags: c

I try to convert unsigned long long to string like this

```
unsigned long long Data = 12;
char Str[20];

sprintf(Str, "%lld",Data);
```

when i want to see
but i always see 00

```
Str[0],Str[1]....;
```

whats the wrong !!!

Comment: Are you sure "%lld" is valid?  I only see "%ld" in the docs.

Comment: This is valid  code as far as I can see (only that you should use `u` instead of `d`). Give us more indications on what you really do, and on what goes wrong.

Comment: If this is for the PIC, then the sprintf support for unsigned long longs is sketchy at best, the problem is in the library files.

Answer (score 4):

In most cases, `%llu` should do the trick. But you might have to use `%I64u` on some Windows platforms.

Comment: OP probably is not using a Windows platform... with USART_transmit('x'); Probably a PIC or Atmega platform.

Answer (score 3):

`%lld` is for signed `long long`, use `%llu` instead.

Answer (score 1):

%llu should work as it was added to standard. however you can use a safe version snprintf or consider writing your own function better than snprintf. Here is one you might be interested in.

```
char *ulltostr(uint64 value, char *ptr, int base)
{
  uint64 t = 0, res = 0;
  uint64 tmp = value;
  int count = 0;

  if (NULL == ptr)
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  if (tmp == 0)
  {
    count++;
  }

  while(tmp > 0)
  {
    tmp = tmp/base;
    count++;
  }

  ptr += count;

  *ptr = '\0';

  do
  {
    res = value - base * (t = value / base);
    if (res < 10)
    {
      * --ptr = '0' + res;
    }
    else if ((res >= 10) && (res < 16))
    {
        * -- ptr = 'A' - 10 + res;
    }
  } while ((value = t) != 0);

  return(ptr);
}
```